# How to exact/assign values from/to a 3D list using logical conditions from 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been blocked by a value assigning/extracting problem concerning python list.
I have a connectivity matrix stored in numpy array:

```
conn = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 3], [0, 3, 0]])
```

What I want to achieve next is: first, create a 3D list `path` in which the ith, jth element is set to a list of length `conn[i, j]`.
To illustrate,

```
path = [ [[] for kk in range(3)] for k in range(3)]
(idx_x, idx_y) = np.nonzero(conn)
non_zero_values = conn[np.nonzero(conn)]
for iter in range(len(non_zero_values)):
    path[idx_x[iter]][idx_y[iter]] = [0 for k in range(non_zero_values[iter])]
```

Second, remove the last value of the list in ith, jth position of `path` like

```
exit_matrix = np.zeros((3, 3))    
for iter in range(len(non_zero_values)):
    exit_matrix[idx_x[iter], idx_y[iter]] = path[idx_x[iter]][idx_y[iter]].pop()
```

Third, insert a value at the beginning of the list in ith, jth position of `path`:

```
enter_matrix = np.array([[0, 4, 0], [2, 0, 1], [0, 3, 0]])
for iter in range(len(non_zero_values)):
    path[idx_x[iter]][idx_y[iter]].insert(0, enter_matrix[idx_x[iter], idx_y[iter]])
```

Is there any efficient way to achieve this? Any suggestions from you would be more than appreciate it. I'm new to python.

Thanks so much for your time to read my question..

Answer (score 0):

`zip` can replace your `iter` loops, and make them easier to read (but probably not faster):

```
for iter in range(len(non_zero_values)):
    path[idx_x[iter]][idx_y[iter]] = [0 for k in range(non_zero_values[iter])]

for i,j,v in zip(idx_x, idx_y, non_zero_values):
    path[i][j] = [0 for k in range(v)]
```

---

```
In [516]: conn = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 3], [0, 3, 0]])
In [517]: path = [ [[] for kk in range(3)] for k in range(3)]
     ...: (idx_x, idx_y) = np.nonzero(conn)
     ...: non_zero_values = conn[np.nonzero(conn)]
     ...: 
In [518]: for i,j,v in zip(idx_x, idx_y, non_zero_values):
     ...:     path[i][j] = [0 for k in range(v)]
     ...:     
In [519]: path
Out[519]: [[[], [0], []], [[0], [], [0, 0, 0]], [[], [0, 0, 0], []]]
```

The variable length of those inner lists suggests strongly that we can't avoid list iterations.  Variable lengths don't mesh well with rectangular multidimensional arrays.

---

Another thing that I'd consider is defining a function to consolidate the action for each `i,j` pair.  That is, do the initialization, pop and insert all in one loop.  A quick glance indicates that the action for one `i,j` pair is independent for the action for another pair.